# Mozilla doesn't refresh the audio tag file. Mozilla's faulty audio

Tags: html, html5-audio

I have a code that auto-generates captcha image by calling a servlet and displays it in an HTML form. But for the visually impaired I wanted to put an audio file as well. So I store the captcha code generated by the servlet as a session attribute in String form and from that attribute again generate an audio file according to the captcha. So lets say if captcha is "c-a-t" the audio file is generated accordingly. Now the problem is when I refresh the page in Chrome the captcha image and audio both get refreshed which is ideal but in Mozilla only the image is getting refreshed not the audio file.

```
    <div class="formRow">
                <div class="field">
                    <img style="margin-left:91px; margin-top:-6px;" class="image" src="http:www.xyz.com/captchaServlet"> 
         //the above line calls a servlet for the image       

                </div>
                </div></br>
                 <div class="formRow">
                      <div class="field">
                      <audio style="margin-left:91px;" controls="controls">
      <source  src="http:www.xyz.com/getSound" type="audio/wav">
//the above line calls servlet for audio file
    Your browser does not support this audio format.
    </audio>
                      </div>
             </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be caching the url. Just use this to make the url unique

```
<source  src="http:www.xyz.com/getSound?rand=<?php echo rand(time()); ?>" type="audio/wav">
```

Comment: You mean calling the same URL is actually making Mozilla not call the URL at all!! You might be right but it is not working..

Comment: I am changing the source URl as well on every window.onload() function but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried changing the source of the audio tag during the `window.onLoad` function, it did not work. When I wrote the script inside the `body` tag however, it worked like a charm. This is what I used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(navigator.userAgent=="Mozilla/5.0 (X19; Ubuntu; Linux i697; rv:10.0) Gecko/22222222 Firefox/16.0"){
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
    document.getElementById("audiowav").src="http://abcd.com/getSound?rand="+n;
  }
</script>
```

So basically I got the idea from @Shahil

Comment: This is strange, I solved my issue using this method as well. Any idea why other browsers don't have this issue whereas Mozilla Firefox specifically has this issue?

Comment: @AnishNarayan Honestly not sure :(

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem and a lot of learning can be gained by solving this bug.

To start with, Mozilla Firefox was unable to figure out the difference between the URL "http:abcd.com/getSound" clicked at different instances. For example, the click at 9:30 AM and the click at 9:31 AM wouldn't have any difference for Firefox because the same URL was requested at both instances.

One simple way to solve this issue is to include a unique parameter at the end of the URL to make sure that Firefox is able to differentiate between web requests.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = (event) => {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
    document.getElementById("audiowav").src="http://abcd.com/getSound?rand="+n;
    };
</script>
```

Adding this on load JS function will change the src URL after each time the page is loaded and since a different URL is called each time, the browser won't find the new URL in its cache and will retrieve the correct audio file for each corresponding click.

The solution is 99% similar to @Nick Div although my curiosity made me dig into more details. I'm still curious to know why this issue specifically occurs in Firefox and not for other browsers. Will return once I find out the answer.